# How do I remove Gas limit on Solidity Code

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, contract-deployment, nextjs

I am new at Solidity and Blockchain. I Have written this solidity code to send all NFTs in wallet.

```
contract MultiERC721Transfer {
    // Mapping to keep track of approved contracts
    mapping(address => bool) public approvedContracts;

    event ApprovedContract(address indexed contractAddress, bool isApproved);

    // Function to approve or revoke an ERC721 contract for transfers
    function approveContract(address _contractAddress, bool _isApproved) public {
        approvedContracts[_contractAddress] = _isApproved;
        emit ApprovedContract(_contractAddress, _isApproved);
    }

    // Function to transfer multiple ERC721 tokens to a recipient
    function safeTransferMultipleERC721Tokens(
        address[] memory _tokenContracts,
        uint256[] memory _tokenIds,
        address _to
    ) external payable{
        require(_tokenContracts.length == _tokenIds.length, "Arrays must have the same length");

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _tokenContracts.length; i++) {
            address tokenContract = _tokenContracts[i];
            uint256 tokenId = _tokenIds[i];

            require(
                IERC721(tokenContract).ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender,
                "Sender does not own the token"
            );

            IERC721(tokenContract).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, _to, tokenId);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
Error: Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (error={"reason":"execution reverted","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","method":"estimateGas","transaction":{"from":"0x37269d114cD1fc0777699B0B20518dbd7D87a7aA","maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x02ed18655c"},"to":"0x11aD4e8426204B868cD5Cfad6D32796B8FA16E53","data":"0x4098da35000000000000000000000000b9373e7d7f54b6d722194c5609d3de85e971ca4e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001","type":2,"accessList":null},"error":{"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":49,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"execution reverted\"}}","error":{"code":-32000},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"type\":\"0x2\",\"maxFeePerGas\":\"0x2ed18655c\",\"maxPriorityFeePerGas\":\"0x59682f00\",\"from\":\"0x37269d114cd1fc0777699b0b20518dbd7d87a7aa\",\"to\":\"0x11ad4e8426204b868cd5cfad6d32796b8fa16e53\",\"data\":\"0x4098da35000000000000000000000000b9373e7d7f54b6d722194c5609d3de85e971ca4e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001\"}],\"id\":49,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/57f5f5f45dcd43f1b40212d6833281ed"}}, tx={"data":"0x4098da35000000000000000000000000b9373e7d7f54b6d722194c5609d3de85e971ca4e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001","to":{},"from":"0x37269d114cD1fc0777699B0B20518dbd7D87a7aA","type":2,"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x02ed18655c"},"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"nonce":{},"gasLimit":{},"chainId":{}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=abstract-signer/5.7.0)
```

When I call the function

```
    const rw = await contract2.safeTransferMultipleERC721Tokens(
      tokenHashes, 
      tokenIds,
      "0x...."
      );
```

Anyone know what could be wrong? I think the problem could be from my Solidity script.

Comment: Your contract most likely doesnt have the approval it needs to transfer the tokens

Comment: @Foxxxey how can I put the approval in the contract?

Comment: This might be helpful. https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that your for has become so large that the necessary gas is  more than a block gas limit and the transaction is too large.It is better to segment your For loop and do it in several transactions to avoid this problem.

Comment: What do you mean Segment my For Ring and do it in several transactions? Kindly explain

Comment: That is, if your For loop transfers 100 NFTs, you divide it by four, and four transactions with the transfer of 25 NFT